# Confusion over boiling point of gallium

Tags: elements, boiling-point

I am completing a project on gallium, and I need to include its boiling point. I thought that this would be fairly simple to look up, however, it appears that different sources quote different temperatures as the boiling point, normally either ~2200 °C or ~2400 °C.

Does anyone know why two different values are presented, or which value is correct?

Below are some examples of websites quoting each figure.

2200 °C:

https://education.jlab.org/itselemental/ele031.html

http://www.rsc.org/periodic-table/element/31/gallium

https://www.livescience.com/29476-gallium.html

2400 °C:

http://www.chemistryexplained.com/elements/C-K/Gallium.html

https://www.britannica.com/science/gallium

http://www.chemicalelements.com/elements/ga.html

Comment: Wikipedia cites 2400 from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231538496_Corrected_Values_for_Boiling_Points_and_Enthalpies_of_Vaporization_of_Elements_in_Handbooks which is article wholly about getting good values.

Comment: In order to help solve this discrepancy, it may be useful to source a graph/equation of vapour pressure versus temperature and find the temperature for a pressure of 1 bar. It is far easier to type an incorrect number than produce an incorrect graph/equation, plus whoever made the graph/equation probably put some effort into ensuring its accuracy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question has been recently raised in [Chemistry & Engineering Letters](https://cen.acs.org/articles/86/i3/Boiling-Gallium.html). The CRC Handbook (2017) in section "*MELTING, BOILING, TRIPLE, AND CRITICAL POINTS OF THE ELEMENTS*" [1, p. 4-117] lists the following values for gallium, quoting original publication [2]:

\begin{align}
t_\mathrm{tp} (\ce{Ga}) &= \pu{29.7666 ^\circ C} \\
t_\mathrm{m} (\ce{Ga}) &= \pu{29.7646 ^\circ C} \\
t_\mathrm{b} (\ce{Ga}) &= \pu{2229 ^\circ C} \\
\end{align}

> [...] values are given for the solid-liquid-gas triple-point temperature $t_\mathrm{tp}$ and pressure $p_\mathrm{tp}$; normal melting point at $\pu{101.325 kPa}$ pressure $t_\mathrm{m}$; normal boiling point $t_\mathrm{b}$; and critical temperature $t_\mathrm{c}$ and pressure $p_\mathrm{c}$. All temperatures are on the [ITS-90 scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Temperature_Scale_of_1990).

#### References

1. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data.; **2017**; Vol. 97. ISBN 978-1-4987-5429-3.
2. Geiger, F.; Busse, C. A.; Loehrke, R. I. *Int J Thermophys* **1987**, 8 (4), 425–436 DOI: [10.1007/BF00567103](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00567103).

Comment: I was hoping someone would check the CRC handbook...

Comment: @NH CRC Handbook is also handy when it comes to pinpointing up-to-date source of information, at least in the majority of cases:)

Comment: We always had a copy of the CRC handbook in our undergrad physics labs as our go-to source.

Comment: You've got twice as much "recently" in the first sentence as you need :)

Comment: The comments section in the C&E letters addresses why this discrepancy existed.